# Jetpack compose: customize radio button group to achieve segmented buttons

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-button

iOS has Segmented controls like this.[image]
I wanna have this in Android by using jetpack compose and I checked there is not build-in like this, and this UI in material 3 doesn't support jetpack compose now. What can I do? Totally customize the radio button? I know I can add the background and text and something, but how can I just hide check mark, make radio button looks like a button? Or there is something library I can use to use UI like Segmented controls? Can anyone give me some hints?

Answer (score 9):

You can use a `Row` of `OutlinedButton` applying an `Offset` to avoid the double border.

Something like:

```
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
    ) {

        val cornerRadius = 16.dp
        var selectedIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(-1) }

        itemsList.forEachIndexed { index, item ->

            OutlinedButton(
                onClick = { selectedIndex = index },
                modifier = when (index) {
                    0 ->
                        Modifier
                            .offset(0.dp, 0.dp)
                            .zIndex(if (selectedIndex == index) 1f else 0f)
                    else ->
                        Modifier
                            .offset((-1 * index).dp, 0.dp)
                            .zIndex(if (selectedIndex == index) 1f else 0f)
                },
                shape = when (index) {
                    0 -> RoundedCornerShape(
                        topStart = cornerRadius,
                        topEnd = 0.dp,
                        bottomStart = cornerRadius,
                        bottomEnd = 0.dp
                    )
                    itemsList.size - 1 -> RoundedCornerShape(
                        topStart = 0.dp,
                        topEnd = cornerRadius,
                        bottomStart = 0.dp,
                        bottomEnd = cornerRadius
                    )
                    else -> RoundedCornerShape(
                        topStart = 0.dp,
                        topEnd = 0.dp,
                        bottomStart = 0.dp,
                        bottomEnd = 0.dp
                    )
                },
                border = BorderStroke(
                    1.dp, if (selectedIndex == index) {
                        Blue500
                    } else {
                        Blue500.copy(alpha = 0.75f)
                    }
                ),
                colors = if (selectedIndex == index) {
                    ButtonDefaults.outlinedButtonColors(
                        containerColor = Blue500.copy(alpha = 0.1f),
                        contentColor = Blue500
                    )
                } else {
                    ButtonDefaults.outlinedButtonColors(
                        containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface,
                        contentColor = Blue500
                    )
                }
            ) {
                Text("Button " + item)
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: If the button text can be multiple lines long and you want to make sure all buttons have the same height, you can add `.height(IntrinsicSize.Min)` to the `Row` modifier and `.fillMaxHeight()` to the `OutlinedButton` modifiers

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be exactly the same as the swiftUI component, you can use this code:

[image]

```
@Composable
fun SegmentedControl(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    items: List<String>,
    defaultSelectedItemIndex: Int = 0,
    useFixedWidth: Boolean = false,
    itemWidth: Dp = 120.dp,
    cornerRadius: Int = 24,
    onItemSelection: (selectedItemIndex: Int) -> Unit
) {
    val selectedIndex = remember { mutableStateOf(defaultSelectedItemIndex) }
    val itemIndex = remember { mutableStateOf(defaultSelectedItemIndex) }

    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(38.dp),
        colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
            containerColor = if (selectedIndex.value == itemIndex.value) {

                MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
            } else {

                MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondary
            }
        ),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(cornerRadius)
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondary),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            items.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
                itemIndex.value = index
                Card(
                    modifier = modifier
                        .weight(1f)
                        .padding(2.dp),
                    onClick = {
                        selectedIndex.value = index
                        onItemSelection(selectedIndex.value)
                    },
                    colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
                        containerColor = if (selectedIndex.value == index) {
                            MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                        } else {
                            MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondary
                        },
                        contentColor = if (selectedIndex.value == index)
                            MaterialTheme.colorScheme.scrim
                        else
                            MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSecondary
                    ),
                    shape = when (index) {
                        0 -> RoundedCornerShape(
                            topStartPercent = cornerRadius,
                            topEndPercent = cornerRadius,
                            bottomStartPercent = cornerRadius,
                            bottomEndPercent = cornerRadius
                        )

                        items.size - 1 -> RoundedCornerShape(
                            topStartPercent = cornerRadius,
                            topEndPercent = cornerRadius,
                            bottomStartPercent = cornerRadius,
                            bottomEndPercent = cornerRadius
                        )

                        else -> RoundedCornerShape(
                            topStartPercent = 0,
                            topEndPercent = 0,
                            bottomStartPercent = 0,
                            bottomEndPercent = 0
                        )
                    },
                ) {
                    Box(modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center){
                        TitleText(
                            text = item,
                            style = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(
                                fontSize = 14.sp,
                                fontWeight = if (selectedIndex.value == index)
                                    LocalTextStyle.current.fontWeight
                                else
                                    FontWeight.Normal,
                                color = if (selectedIndex.value == index)
                                    MaterialTheme.colorScheme.scrim
                                else
                                    MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSecondary
                            ),
                            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,

                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```